# Insert in a table and update another table if new ID matches

Tags: mysql, triggers

**Table1:** `id, inserted_in_table2`

**Table2:** `table1_id, amount`

I want to update `Table1.inserted_in_table2=TRUE` after data is inserted in **Table2** AND `Table2.table1_id = Table1.id`;

I am creating the trigger first:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table2_trig AFTER INSERT ON Table2
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Table1
 SET inserted_in_table2=TRUE
WHERE id = NEW.table1_id;
```

Then executing Insert in Table2:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (table1_id, amount)
 SELECT 
      table1_id,
      amount
FROM Other_Table;
```

The error I get:

> [HY000][1442] Can't update table 'Table1' in stored function/trigger
> because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
> function/trigger.

How can I fix it?

Comment: If `Other_Table` happens to be table1, then you cannot use a trigger for this operation.

Comment: @Shadow the Other_Table contains JOIN operation with Table1

Comment: Then you cannot use trigger to update table1.